# IOS: delegate methods for two tableView

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

myaI have this code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


if (tableView == firstTableView){

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease] ; 
}

cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

return cell;
}
}
```

I check if tableview is firsttableview, but it give me a warning because the method haven't a "return" cell, how can I solve?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do.  What do you mean by "the method haven't a 'return cell'"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only return a cell if the table is `firstTableView`. Make sure you return a cell for other tables by adding a return statement outside of your conditional.

Answer (score 1):

Your code needs to return a value for all paths through that method. So, if your check for firstTableView fails, you still need to return a valid `UITableViewCell` from the method. You should probably read the [UITableView programming guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451) - it walks you through proper usage of a tableview.